# Permit page, if login form custom form was successful

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I am very new to Spring Security. In Angular I have a custom form that sends a post to this controller:

```java
@RestController
public class LoginController {
    @PostMapping("/login")
    public ResponseEntity<String> login(@RequestBody User user) {
        if (user.getUsername().equals("linda") && user.getPassword().equals("pass")) {
            return ResponseEntity.ok("Access granted");
        }
        return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body("Access denied");
    }
}
```

If the login was successful, the user should have access to the page `/welcome`, otherwise this page should be forbidden.

This is what I have tried:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class Config {
    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(10);
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/welcome").hasAnyRole("ADMIN")
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin(form -> form.loginPage("/login").permitAll());
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public InMemoryUserDetailsManager userDetailsManager() {
        var linda = User.builder()
                .username("linda")
                .password(passwordEncoder().encode("pass"))
                .roles("ADMIN")
                .build();
        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(linda);
    }
}
```

When I call */login*, I get the status *405 - Method Not Allowed*.

[image]

Probably I am doing everything wrong. How can this be done correctly?

Comment: Your login endpoint is expecting "Post" method however once you call "http://localhost:8080/login" you're using "Get" method. Try to use postman to simulate "/login" using "Post" method instead

Comment: @Phoenician I have tried the same with Postman using the POST method. The body is `{
    "username": "linda",
    "password": "pass"
}` but I still get the 405 status.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's 2 things that should be updated in your login endpoint :

1. `@PostMapping("login")` should be `@PostMapping("/login")`
2. You should either define a class containing username and password as fields and update your endpoint parameters to the below :

   `public ResponseEntity<String> login(@RequestBody CustomUser customUser) {`

   or you could use it as follow :
   `public ResponseEntity<String> login(@RequestParam(value = "username") String username, @RequestParam(value = "password") String password) {`

**UPDATE :**

```
Following your update, i've resimulate your scenario and the configuration is wrong as you've already mentioned.
```

Configuration should be as follow and there's no need to create a login endpoint :

```
@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(10);
}

@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/login", "/loginFailed").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/welcome").hasAnyRole("ADMIN").anyRequest()
            .authenticated().and()
            .formLogin(form -> form.loginPage("/login")
                    .usernameParameter("username")
                    .passwordParameter("password")
                    .defaultSuccessUrl("/welcome")
                    .failureUrl("/loginFailed"));
    return http.build();
}

@Bean
public InMemoryUserDetailsManager userDetailsManager() {
    UserDetails linda = User.builder().username("linda")
            .password(passwordEncoder().encode("pass")).roles("ADMIN")
            .build();
    return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(linda);
}
```

However username and password should be submitted in the query param as per the default configuration in "UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter". You could change the default behavior by implementing your Custom UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter. (Check [this](https://insource.io/blog/articles/custom-authentication-with-spring-boot.html))

[image]

Endpoints :

```
@GetMapping("/welcome")
public ResponseEntity<String> welcome(Authentication authentication) {
    return ResponseEntity.ok("Weclome [" + authentication.getName() + "]");
}

@GetMapping("/loginFailed")
public ResponseEntity<String> login() {
    return ResponseEntity.ok("Failed to login");
}
```

Hope it helps